# VBA(?): Document Microsoft Access Database to dataset (list tables/fields/queries w/ fields)

Tags: ms-access, vba

Looking for a way in which I can grab an Access database and export something along the likes like:

```
| Type           |   Name       |   Field     |     Field Type      |     Example values         |  SQL                                     |
| Table          |   Table1     |   Field1    |     String          |     Field example 1/2/3    |                                          | 
| Table          |   Table1     |   Field2    |     String          |     Field example 1/2/3    |                                          |
| Table          |   Table1     |   Field3    |     String          |     Field example 1/2/3    |                                          |
| ViewOutput     | SelectedCols |   Field 1   |     ...             |     Field example 1/2/3    |                                          |
| ViewOutput     | SelectedCols |   Field 2   |     ...             |     Field example 1/2/3    |                                          |
| ViewDefinition | SelectedCols |   Field 1   |     Field Type      |                            |  SELECT [field1], [field2] from [Table1] |
```

In other words:

- Spreadsheet/dataset in which is presented

  - All tables by name, and underlying fieldnames / types / a few example column values presented (*)
  - All views by name, along with the fieldnames defined and example values (*)

* ideally/optionally I get three dinstinct comma separated example field values

This would be an amazing starting point in moving from Access to a more serious database, help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question, in itself, is too broad, as it requires a whole lot of code to connect Access to Excel, iterate through tables and queries, get example values from tables, etc. However, Access does have the database documenter built-in that does about half of this on the click of a button.

Comment: Excel output is optional, as long as its tabular data that comes out (e.g. CSV). A decent answer could be how to expose / read the internals in VBA Access to export / further process, IMHO not too broad. I can imagine the distinct values from to make it too broad, made it optional.

Comment: Lastly: the Access database documenter exports non-structured data (PDF), IMHO not a viable solution .

Comment: You can look at `ADO` and then use this to connect to the database, and open the schema, `connection.openschema()` look at the arguments for this, to tell you the majority of what you want, the I'd suggest you do a `select top x` query on the tables to give you your example results.

Comment: @MattV Access database documenter creates a report. You can do with that report as you wish, export the underlying data to Excel, print it to pdf, copy the text to a text file, you name it. There's even a separate button to export it to Excel in print preview.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/a/438407) there is an example of getting tables and fields. You can adap it also to get queries just changing a few words (iinstead of `For Each tdf In db.TableDefs` you should do `For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, **this question is, indeed, too broad and no effort has been shown**, but at least you can have a start point. I did a code that list tables and queries (excluding SYS tables, but you can adap it to your needs). It also lists fields names and types.

About getting example values, for that you would need to open a recordset for each object, doing this code pretty much time consuming. Also, you ask for 1-3 values, when it could be that a query/table has 0,1 or 2, so also must check every time the record count and so on. **So I have ignored that part.**

But at least the code will get tables and queries with names, fields and fieldnames.

**BONUS:** Yes, it will get the SQL code of queries too.

```
Private Sub SHOW_DB_INFO()

Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Double

Dim AppExcel As Object
Dim WK As Object

Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
AppExcel.Visible = False
AppExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
AppExcel.Workbooks.Add

Set WK = AppExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet




Set db = CurrentDb


For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
   If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then ' Don't enumerate the system tables
      For x = 0 To tdf.Fields.Count - 1
        i = i + 1
        WK.Range("A" & i).Value = "Table"
        WK.Range("B" & i).Value = tdf.Name
        WK.Range("C" & i).Value = tdf.Fields(x).Name
        WK.Range("D" & i).Value = FLD_TYPENAME(tdf.Fields(x).Type) 'enumeration can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/datatypeenum-enumeration-dao
      Next x
   End If
Next tdf

Dim qdf As QueryDef
For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
    For x = 0 To qdf.Fields.Count - 1
        i = i + 1
        WK.Range("A" & i).Value = "Query"
        WK.Range("B" & i).Value = qdf.Name
        WK.Range("C" & i).Value = qdf.Fields(x).Name
        WK.Range("D" & i).Value = FLD_TYPENAME(qdf.Fields(x).Type)
        WK.Range("E" & i).Value = qdf.SQL
    Next x
Next qdf

AppExcel.Visible = True
AppExcel.ScreenUpdating = True

Set WK = Nothing
Set AppExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

You'll need also this UDF

```
Private Function FLD_TYPENAME(ByVal vType As Integer) As String
Select Case vType
    Case Is = 101: FLD_TYPENAME = "Attachment data"
    Case Is = 16: FLD_TYPENAME = "Big Integer data"
    Case Is = 9: FLD_TYPENAME = "Binary data"
    Case Is = 1: FLD_TYPENAME = "Boolean (True/False) data"
    Case Is = 2: FLD_TYPENAME = "Byte (8-bit) data"
    Case Is = 18: FLD_TYPENAME = "Text data (fixed width)"
    Case Is = 102: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-valued byte data"
    Case Is = 108: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-value decimal data"
    Case Is = 106: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-value double-precision floating-point data"
    Case Is = 107: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-value GUID data"
    Case Is = 103: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-value integer data"
    Case Is = 104: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-value long integer data"
    Case Is = 105: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-value single-precision floating-point data"
    Case Is = 109: FLD_TYPENAME = "Multi-value Text data (variable width)"
    Case Is = 5: FLD_TYPENAME = "Currency data"
    Case Is = 8: FLD_TYPENAME = "Date value data"
    Case Is = 20: FLD_TYPENAME = "Decimal data (ODBCDirect only)"
    Case Is = 7: FLD_TYPENAME = "Double-precision floating-point data"
    Case Is = 21: FLD_TYPENAME = "Floating-point data (ODBCDirect only)"
    Case Is = 15: FLD_TYPENAME = "GUID data"
    Case Is = 3: FLD_TYPENAME = "Integer data"
    Case Is = 4: FLD_TYPENAME = "Long Integer data"
    Case Is = 11: FLD_TYPENAME = "Binary data (bitmap)"
    Case Is = 12: FLD_TYPENAME = "Memo data (extended text)"
    Case Is = 19: FLD_TYPENAME = "Numeric data (ODBCDirect only)"
    Case Is = 6: FLD_TYPENAME = "Single-precision floating-point data"
    Case Is = 10: FLD_TYPENAME = "Text data (variable width)"
    Case Is = 22: FLD_TYPENAME = "Data in time format (ODBCDirect only)"
    Case Is = 23: FLD_TYPENAME = "Data in time and date format (ODBCDirect only)"
    Case Is = 17: FLD_TYPENAME = "Variable Binary data (ODBCDirect only)"
    Case Else: FLD_TYPENAME = "Not found/Unknown"
End Select

End Function
```

The code must be executed from Access itself. Paste both codes in a module, and execute it.

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: This is absolutely terrific, I'll puzzle to get the last column with example values. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thx for your words. I must admit I normally do not post answer when OP has shown no effort, but in your case, you have almost 1000 rep so I guess you've helped in the past other users in other areas, and I did it :). Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to print out or export the structure is built in to access.

From the ribbon, under database tools, choose database Documenter.

Choose tables tab, select the tables you want to report on.

BEFORE you hit ok, make sure you hit options like this:

[image]

The result is then like this:

[image]
While viewing the above, you can print, or even export to excel.

Comment: I dare you to use the database documenter on the Students MS template db and export to excel and report back on the experience.